# UIButton Image Auto Scaling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `UIButton` which contains a image / icon on the left.
The text in the `UIButton` is given in by a selected cell from UICollectionView.

The problem I am having is that when the text is too large it resizes the button image.

I have '`Line Break`' option to word wrap in the Storyboard.
I have '`Content Mode`' to Aspect Fill in the Storyboard option.

I am setting the text using the following code:

```
address.setTitle(address, for: .normal)
```

**The expected output should be like this:**
[image: 1]

**The actual output is this:**

[image: 2]

Is there any other option I should be tweaking?

Comment: set width and height for the image. on your constraints.

Comment: Try to set a proper size of an image or set button image insets

Comment: If you want your button to show always the same image size then do the following: `yourButton.imageView?.contentMode = .center`. This prevents the button from resizing the image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would fix your problem:
`button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

Comment: nope. i have tried all contentMode including .redraw, .centre, .scaleAspectFit, 
i have even tried to reset the image after updating the title by using 
       addressLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "Address"), for: .normal